# Amazon EC2 + 301 www redirection

Tags: apache, redirect, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm running a site on AmazonEC2 instance, and so far everything is ok, except a single glitch. When I navigate to

www.mysite.com/somepage.html

, browser happily opens the desired page. But when I try

mysite.com/somepage.html

, I go to the root of my site, i.e. to

www.mysite.com

LiveHTTPHeaders tells me that 301 redirection occurs. So here's the question: what configuration files do I need to change to make redirection respect URL path?

Also, I noticed that nginx does the redirection. Does it mean that redirection is happening outside of EC2 instance or not?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should have some kind of settings that is redirecting your request from `http://mysite.com/` to `http://www.mysite.com/`

Following is kind of conf. settings you should find in your `nginx.conf` or inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/<site-vhost-name>`

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

This tells NGINX to redirect request from `http://mysite.com/` to `http://www.mysite.com/`.

If yes?, then blindly remove those two lines of conf.

Comment: "You should have some kind of settings that is redirecting your request" - well, the very question is the location of this settings file :) I don't have the "/etc/nginx" on my EC2 instance, unfortunatelly, so I wonder if redirection occurs outside of my instance.

Comment: @Dmitry which OS you are running on your EC2 machine?

Comment: it was Ubuntu, sorry for that late answer.